# Simultaneously binding a tuple and its destructured elements in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm destructuring a tuple and binding its elements to variables in an Erlang function signature, like so:

```
store({X, Y}, State) ->
    ...
```

But sometimes I need to bind the source tuple *and* its contents. So far I've handled that with an extra line of code:

```
store(Point, State) ->
  {X, Y} = Point,
  ...
```

But I'm new to Erlang and wonder if this is naive. My question is inspired by binding in a Scala extraction:

```
case point@Point(x, y) => ???
```

Is there a better way to bind the tuple and its contents at the same time, or is it best to destructure the tuple in a separate assignment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write

```
store({X, Y} = Point, State) ->
  ...
```

which works similarly to the Scala example.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

`store({X, Y}, State) ->
    ...`
 
In this case, when you invoke a function like `mod:store({x, y, z}, state)`, it will raise an exception:
`error: no function clause matching mod:store{x, y, z}, state)`；

while if you use

`store(Point, State) ->
  {X, Y} = Point,
  ...`

In this case, when you invoke a function like `mod:store({x, y, z}, state)`, it will raise an exception:
`error: no match of right hand side value {x, y, z}
     in function  mod:store/2`；